# How to type a es6 object/dictionary in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

For example, I have the below type and I'm using an es6 object to serve as a dictionary.

```
type User = {
    id: string,
    name: string   
}
const usersDict = { [key: string]: User  } = {}
```

But the problem is if I try to get a nonexistent user id, the above typing isn't correct. e.g.

```
const user = usersDict['user_id_that_doesnt_exist'] // type of user is User
```

Should I type `usersDict` as below instead?

```
const usersDict = { [key: string]: User | undefined } = {}
```

The problem for this one would be when looping through the values in the below example

```
const usersDict = { [key: string]: User | undefined } = {}
Object.values(usersDict).map((user)=>{
    // here the type of user is User|undefined, 
    // but it really should be just User type,
    // since it's impossible to be undefined
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use [`noUncheckedIndexAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) in your `tsconfig` then you'll get [all the behavior you want](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwBpsoKBDAWwmNPOswF9NNRIsBIgAiuAMbBcAeyaIQqDPQDaAV2EBJIiTKUqAXWLwkPPuNmko6pHDGSjwu1NmN5i9NwDcZi8CvDFa0RbCWBlAHIggH0CKOAAC0ZgKPxpCDgKZIgAD1xScP0oAHoiqAFoaQAzfyQ8OCFagB8rCnwISsoIfD4AeQAjACsISQA6ADdGABtVdIAKIJDJAEoR5kYwWfnhJZQAPiwcHBKoeKRoBPPwCuqguobEGihGera4XEQuniWgA):

```js
type User = {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

type UserDictionary = {
  [userId: string]: User
}

const usersDict: UserDictionary = {};

const user = usersDict['user_id_that_doesnt_exist'] // type of user is User | undefined

Object.values(usersDict).map((user)=>{
    // here the type of user is User, as desired
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`" User | undefined "` actually means you are saving keys with undefined as value, but according to your statement that is not true.

The issue is in understand what is a null check for, if you defined an object in a variable then you essentially give it two states (null || object) as null being the default state.

If your code always assigns the value to an object and since null is not an expected state, you will never put a null check for it or define null as expected value, otherwise it might not throw error where it should.

> `Object.values(usersDict)` will never a undefined value unless you
> explicitly add an key with undefined value `usersDict['user_id']= undefined`;

Comment: That makes sense, and sounds like the solution you are alluding to is to handle it elsewhere, e.g. wrap usersDict['key'] into my own function and check if key exists myself first before returning.

Comment: Yes in the sense of it, the typescript type should only indicate what you ctually want to save in it.

Comment: @Arch1tect  i have added the last bit in the answer, is there still a doubt

Comment: no doubts, you totally get what I'm trying to do here. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[Partial<User>][1]` for this case.

```js
type User = {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

type Dictionary = Partial<Record<string, User>>

const usersDict: Dictionary = {}

const user = usersDict['user_id_that_doesnt_exist'] // type of user is User | undefined

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

(Object.values(usersDict) as Array<NonNullable<Values<Dictionary>>>)
  .map((user /** User */) => { })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwBpsoKBDAWwmNPOswF9NNRIUACK4AxsFwB7JohCooABUaIJjADYAeAEoRRkxPg0dKtWAkQA+C3z0VSUAK7m4I8cVcTpyuWnS9MtvZOSPLBiC5iwADaAORhAPoE8cAAFozA8fiSEHAUGRAAHrikMQC6UAD0FVAC0JIAZo7meHBmSHy1UABq6g45GgAqFvIDUQDWECANUAOlfAAUAPIARgBWusAAdABuvTnzYRHiAJRQjK0AgoiIjCAaAHLS9w5qaozLahAaPWp9cBoeKQyEBWCzHeibZiMMDzA7NCoAKgRbWQCIqpxQw3QUG4xyAA)

I have used type assertion `as Array<...>` because `Dictionary` should be typed as `Partial` and as far as I understood `usersDict['user_id_that_doesnt_exist']` should return `User | undefined`

Comment: What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: My bad, I should have wrap Record<string, User> into Partial.

Comment: that is still a wrong solution, read her question, it's not about trying to get   "User | undefined " its more about how handle keys that does not exist in the dictionary, where you are trying to justify that { 'key': undefined  } can exist. you should also go and re-read my answer.

Comment: But OP claims that `usersDict['user_id_that_doesnt_exist']` is wrongly typed

Comment: No the OP claims  "I try to get a nonexistent user id", she is not saying dictionary keys are the property of User

Comment: Let's wait for OP comment

Comment: I'm using the `usersDict` object as a dictionary, when I do `usersDict['user_id']`, I'm trying to find a user with that user id and it's possible the user hasn't been added to the dictionary yet. Sry about the confusion, feel free to help edit my post.

Comment: @Arch1tect please let me know whether my solution works for you or not

Comment: @captain-yossarian I would disagree with "usersDict['user_id_that_doesnt_exist'] should return User | undefined", it depends if returning an undefined is part of acceptable response or not, treat dictionary as any property, if you do not actively expect to hold 'user_Key' = undefined, it should never indicate so because this could be an error state